# Programatically Applying Theme (spcolor) takes too long

Tags: 2013, branding, theme, style.css

I have a branding solution that uses the ApplyTheme like this :

```
foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
  web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
  web.Update();
  web.ApplyTheme(themeUrl, "", "", true);
}
```

The problem being, this call to `.ApplyTheme()` takes forever! It probably adds an extra 10 - 15 seconds on each iteration. Why does this take so long? I'd like to eliminate the Theme all together but I would have to override numerous Core15.CSS classes to get the same branding my Theme provides.

How do I speed up this ApplyTheme or better yet, consolidate the Core15.css with my custom style.css to eliminate the need for a Theme?

Comment: Couldn't you combine all your classes into your custom_styles.css file and in the RootWeb, use that as the Alternate CSS link and push it down to all subsites? I'm doing that in a SPO site collection to standardize the width of the global nav hovers, just not doing it programmatically.

Comment: So basically, you mean take Core15.css when the Theme was applied and merge it with Style.css. Then remove the Theme? Then there's no use for Core15.css anymore I guess

Comment: I mean, you put all your CSS changes necessary into a single file, and apply that using the alternate CSS link. If your theme contained a custom CSS file and you had an additional CSS file on top of that, merge them into a single file, and apply that to the site using Alternate CSS in the Masterpage settings and don't use a theme at all.

Comment: That'd be ideal. I already have custom_style.css applied, but there are hundreds of classes in Core that are affected by the Theme. I can't copy the entire Core file into my custom_style.css that would be overkill